# How to update view based on nestedlist item in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am looking for refresh the view, when some nested item changed in list.

Main list is `rt.projects()`, I find some nested element using ID, I called it as `match` and add one item in nested list (`SelectedMembersForProject`)

I want to update that newly added value to view, how could I do it?

Here is code what I wrote:

```
case "Project":
    debugger
    var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(rt.projects(), function (item) {
        return item.Soid === ui.item.SourceSoid;
    });
    debugger;
    if (match) {
        var indexVal = rt.projects.indexOf(match)
        var AddItem = {
            MemberProfileId : ui.item.MemberSoid,
            MembeImageName: ui.item.ImageFileName,
            MemberName: ui.item.Name
        };
        match.SelectedMembersForProject.push(AddItem);
        rt.projects.replace(rt.projects()[indexVal], match);
    }
    break;
```

Still I am not able to see my newly added value in VIEW!, what's wrong?

Following image should get some more ideas
http://postimg.org/image/jx8n6516f/
http://postimg.org/image/5wx6cg4fn/

Comment: Have you tried calling `rt.projects.valueHasMutated()` after calling `projects.replace(...)`?

Comment: Yes, i wrote that already, but no result :(

Comment: Is your `project.SelectedMembersForProject` object an `observableArray`? Also, I see that you have debugger statements in there, did you check to see that `match` is actually truthy? The jsfiddle I whipped up seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hjhyn/

Comment: Yes, i am going to post whole stuff, in pastebin give me few mins

Comment: my whole code is something like this : http://pastebin.com/G9Avz6zG, i never declared SelectedMembersForProject as observableArray, cause it's part of my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from the code you posted, the issue is that your `SelectedMembersForProject` object is not an observableArray. What you could do when your data is retrieved from the server, translate the dataset into a knockout-friendly model.

It won't be fun to write, but that should solve your problem.

See here for a working example (where the child array *is* an observable array): http://jsfiddle.net/hjhyn/

.. and here for a reproduction of your issue (where the child array *is not* an observable array): http://jsfiddle.net/hjhyn/1/

Comment: Yes, you are right, but problem is, how could  translate the dataset into a knockout-friendly model.:), i will do some work on this, once i am finishing with this issue, i will mark as answer :) thank you very much

Comment: @jamesC You'll have to do that manually in most scenarios. You could take a look at the `ko.mapping` plugin to see if that might suit your needs here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html